# Duke of Frías це герцог Фріаса чи Фріаський, чи інакше?

Tags: from-english

Як правильно перекласти [Duke of Frias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_of_Fr%C3%ADas)? [Фріас](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%81_(%D0%91%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81)) це місто і там є [замок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA), в якому ці герцоги жили.